# Spring Integration xml to java dsl - how to define inbound/outbound channel adaptors, pollers, etc

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-integration, dsl

This is my spring integration xml: A simple stuff i'm using for learning...

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="executionMessageFileInputChannel"
                                  directory="file:${fpml.messages.input}"
                                  prevent-duplicates="false" filename-pattern="*.xml">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="20000" max-messages-per-poll="20"/>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:service-activator input-channel="executionMessageFileInputChannel"
                       output-channel="executionMessageFileArchiveChannel"
                       ref="dummyService" method="myMethod"/>


<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter id="executionMessageFileArchiveChannel"
                                   directory="file:${fpml.messages.archive}"
                                   delete-source-files="true" auto-create-directory="true"/>
```

I couldn't really find a good tutorial on this.. could you please point me to 
**a good tutorial for integration java dsl?**
Also, please **help me convert this from xml to dsl.**

**UPDATE:** (after [Gary's Response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31724538/1866983)) :

I managed to translate it till this.

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface Archive {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "archiveFile.input")
    void archive();
}

@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow archiveFile() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(dirPath))
                                .patternFilter("*.xml")
                                .preventDuplicatesFilter(false),
                        e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(20000)
                                .maxMessagesPerPoll(20)))
                .handle("app","myMethod")
                .handle(Files.outboundAdapter(new File(outDirPath)).deleteSourceFiles(true).autoCreateDirectory(true))
                .get();
    }
```

Just not sure if this I'm doing it right. Posted it as soon as I translated, will test it out.

Tested it : getting the following error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'archiveFile' defined in
>   si.jdsl.App: Bean instantiation via
>   factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow]:
>   Factory method 'archiveFile' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The 'filter'
>   (org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter@48e64352)
>   is already configured for the FileReadingMessageSource

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE 2:**

Thanks Gary, That solved the filter issue: Getting issue with service activator. Following is my service activator:

```
@Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "archiveFile.input")
    public Message<File> myMethod (File inputFile){
        Map<String, Object> contextHeader = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        return new GenericMessage<File>(inputFile, contextHeader);
    }
```

> Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'myMethod' defined in
>   si.jdsl.App: Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type
>   [java.io.File]: : No qualifying bean of type [java.io.File] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [java.io.File] found for dependency: expected
>   at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this
>   dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

Please let me know what i'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Files` namespace factory. See [the DSL reference manual](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference). There's a general tutorial [here](https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/25/spring-integration-java-dsl-line-by-line-tutorial) which walks through a line-by-line conversion of the cafe sample app. (Java 6/7 version [here](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/01/spring-integration-java-dsl-pre-java-8-line-by-line-tutorial)).

**EDIT**:

This looks like a bug, the DSL is complaining that you are setting two filters and it won't allow it.

In this case, you actually don't need this

```
.preventDuplicatesFilter(false),
```

because that's the default when you provide another filter.

If you do need to compose a filter you can use

```
.filter(myFilter())
```

where `myFilter` is a `CompositeFileListFilter` bean with pattern filter etc.

**EDIT 2**:

`@Bean`s are constructed at initialization time, clearly this is a runtime method.

[See the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#d4e15193).

When a `@Bean` is annotated with `@ServiceActivator`, it must be of type `MessageHandler`. To use POJO messaging, you need a `@MessageEndpoint` bean...

```
@Bean
public MyPojo myPojo() {
    return new MyPojo();
}

@MessageEndpoint
public static class MyPojo {

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "archiveFile.input")
    public Message<File> myMethod (File inputFile){
        Map<String, Object> contextHeader = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        return new GenericMessage<File>(inputFile, contextHeader);
    }

}
```

You can have multiple messaging methods in the POJO.

Comment: I've updated my question with my progress. Please have a look and let me know what i'm missing. Ta.

Comment: Great, that sorted the filter issue. now i'm facing issues with service activator. Please help.

Comment: You are a Genius! and very very helpful.. Hats off to you sir! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "fileInputChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000"))
    public MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource() {
        CompositeFileListFilter<File> filters =new CompositeFileListFilter<>();
        filters.addFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.log"));
        filters.addFilter(new LastModifiedFileFilter());

        FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
        source.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
        source.setDirectory(new File(DIRECTORY));
        source.setFilter(filters);

        return source;
    }
```